# android navigation graph configration change

Tags: android, navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am trying to follow single activity pattern with android navigation component and my %99 of fragment are portrait but I need to make a new fragment can be portrait or landscape without adding new activity how can I achieve. I could't find any resource. is it possible ? if it is how ?

Comment: Try this https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#1 code labs tutorials

Comment: it's say nothing about orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener` and set orientation according to the current fragment.

Add this in your activity's `onCreate`:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.your_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
navHostFragment.navController..addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
    if (destination.id == R.id.destination_with_orientation) {
        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR
    } else {
        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following steps could be useful for you:

1. Don't lock screen orientation from `AndroidManifest.xml`.
2. Register a listener inside `Activity` on the `childFragmentManager` of the `NavHostFragment`, that will execute callbacks on fragment lifecycle change

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   //...
   
   val fragments = supportFragmentManager.fragments
   check(fragments.size == 1) {
       val baseMessage = "Expected 1 fragment to host the app's navigation. Instead found ${fragments.size}."
       if (fragments.size == 0) {
           val suggestion = "(Make sure you specify `android:name=\"androidx.navigation.fragment." +
                   "NavHostFragment\"` or override setUpNavigationGraph)"
           "$baseMessage $suggestion"

       } else baseMessage
   }

   with(fragments[0].childFragmentManager) {
       registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(CustomFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(), false)
   }
}

private inner class CustomFragmentLifecycleCallbacks : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
   override fun onFragmentViewCreated(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment, v: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {}
   override fun onFragmentViewDestroyed(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment) {}
}
```

3. Follow this [guide](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/21077/lock-screen-s-rotation-programmatically) to lock/unlock screen orientation depending upon which `Fragment` is visible, from the above callback.

---

**NOTE**

Fragment tags or instance type could be used for writing conditional statements inside the lifecycle callbacks, based on app's navigation design.

Don't forget to [unregisterFragmentLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#unregisterFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks)) from `Activity.onDestroy()`

---

*Cheers*